# Connecting SATA DVD drive to USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, sata, dvd

I know there is a lot of questions like this but this is different.

I have only 2 sata ports which are occupied by a SSD and a HDD.
But I have **extra Molex power connector**. And the DVD drive is old which has SATA power and also the Molex 4 pin power input.
I also have a SATA to USB convertor used for 2.5 inch sata HDDs, which I removed from an external Seagate HDD.

But this SATA to USB convertor doesn't have enough power to power the DVD drive.

*So my question is "Can I power the DVD drive using molex and connect the SATA to USB to get the data from the DVD drive?"*

The only problem is the SATA to USB also provide a little power to the DVD drive. Does it fries the DVD board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CABLESETC Sata Extension Cable Adapter Jointer 30cm - Sata 7 Pin Male to Sata 7 Pin Female https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07FLWMWMD/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_C7ZFGYE48ZXR94FXE501

I have cut the sides of this SATA male part to connect it to the USB 3.0 to SATA converter.

PiBOX India - USB 3.0 to 2.5" SATA III Hard Drive Adapter 0.5 M Long Cable w/UASP - SATA to USB 3.0 Converter for SSD/HDD - Hard Drive Adapter Cable - 50 cm -ASM1153e Chipset - 2.5 inch HDD https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07KDKNT29/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_2B7DVRZHXQR1CKQK0J06

Then I connected the data cable to this converter.
Then I connected the SATA power cable from the power supply to the DVD drive and connected the male part of the SATA male to female from the first image to the DVD drive.

Finally I connected the USB 3.0 to SATA cable usb part to the usb port.

Now the DVD drive gets the power from the PSU and works as an USB DVD drive.

For a USB converter with a power adapter, I could easily buy a sleek External DVD drive which is power efficient but I had money constraints.

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have bought a SATA <-> USB adapter, and that adapter came with an external power supply and adapters to molex.

[image: SATA via USB adapter with separate power supply]

So it should work as long as the correct power is supplied to the correct pins.
Also (AFAIK) the SATA connector does not provide any power for the drive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is very costly in India and for that price I could buy an external dvd drive. This is costly. What I now do is I use an SATA to usb and connect only the SATA data cable to it using a male to female sata data cable. Then connect the SATA data cable to the DVD drive which directs to the USB and for power I purchased a SATA power splitter and connected to the SATA power port of DVD drive. Works perfectly.

Comment: I can't remember the price exactly, but it was below 30€ (the USB3 variant would be more expensive, however). Another possible alternative would be to but a complete external case with USB to SATA adapter and external power supply. Back to the original question: if the adapter you have also provides power via the SATA (not MOLEX) power pins, it's probably a bad idea to connect the MOLEX pins, too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I was also not sure about the dual power but I never did. I extended the SATA data cable using a male and female and connected the female to the SATA to usb 3.0 cable (this one can only power a 2.5 inch HDD) which i got for 6 dollars and it burns disk perfectly. The total price is 6 for the converter, 4 for SATA male to female and 3 for a SATA power splitter. The SATA to usb with an adapter costs huge more and for that I could get a new external DVD burner. Plus now I could salvage everything except the SATA male to female.